# JSF EL: Fallback if l18n-Propperty not found

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2, el

In my JSF project, i have something like this

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg[foo]}" />
```

where *msg* is my ResourceBundle and *foo* is the variable for the identifier of the properties, containing for example *label.car*, so that the code would return either *car* or *Auto* (internationalization).

**The problem:**

If *foo* is set to a property identifier which doesn't exist in the ResourceBundle, lets say *boat*, the app, of course, crashes with a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`.

While in Spring there is a way to handle this as a fallback with a default message..

```
<spring:message code="${foo}" text="${foo}" />
```

(returning the identifier itself instead of it's internationalized value)

..I was not able to do this in JSF.

Any hints how something similar to this is possible in JSF? Thanks!

//**Update:**
 - Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
 - Apache MyFaces-2
 - PrimeFaces 3.3
 - tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1
 - Java version number: 1.7.0_05
 - Hibernate 3.5.6-Final

Comment: try "#{msg.fooNew}" this should give you %%fooNew%% , thats what you were looking for?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think so. I want the content of _foo_ just is there is no property named like the content of _foo_. btw: Calling the property via getter (. instead of []) will not work because there are no getters for ressourcePropperties..)

Comment: sure there is a getter , here an online ref ... http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/ look for Example 1

Comment: ach, okay, yeah. but I am in the 'For a key that has a dot “.” as name' case... ;)

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace and mention the exact JSF impl/version used? This behaviour is namely strange, it should print `???foo???` instead.

Comment: As per your edit, you're using MyFaces. That'll probably be MyFaces specific. Mojarra doesn't throw that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'solved' the problem by [adding my own tag](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1558/) imitating the Spring-behavior by doing this:

(excerpt of my TagHandler implementation)

```
value = getAttribute("value").getValue(context);
...
key = getAttribute("key").getValue(context);
...
if (key != null) {
  try {
    w.write(String.format("%s", getLocalizedString(key, bundle)));
  } catch (final Exception cause) {
    if (value != null) {
      w.write(String.format("%s", value));
    } else {
      // exception / invalid key
    }
  }

} else if (value != null) {
  w.write(String.format("%s", value));
} else {
  // exception / do noting
}
```

So I am able to use this like:

```
<my:outputText key="#{key}" value="#{fallback_value}" />
```